# grid view get items which are visible to user

Tags: android, gridview

I am showing images in a grid view [around 100 images] and those images will refresh after 10 second .i want to refresh only those images which are visible to user.how can i get only visible items from grid view so i can request server to fetch **only** those images which are visible to user?

Comment: Please don't repeat the same question, update this question if you have anything new to add.

Answer (score 8):

```
for(int i = 0; i < GridView.getChildCount(); i++) {
   if(GridView.getChildAt(i).isVisible())
      // do what you need
}
```

You should consider that this is abstract code snippet, just illustrated approach to resolve your problem

**Edit:** The better way in my opinion:

```
for(int visiblePosition = GridView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); visiblePosition <= GridView.getLastVisiblePosition(); visiblePosition++) {
   View view = GridView.getChildAt(visiblePosition);
   // make something
}
```

Comment: thanks it works, Actually when user scrolls gridview 'onScrollStateChanged' and when state goes to 'OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE' condition. I am checking for visible child and requesting only those images from server.

Comment: getChildAt doesn't work on item's position but on child views position which is usually not same. Your edited solution will throw exception if items are more than visible.

Comment: Plus, there is no `isVisible` method in `View` class

Answer (score 3):

You can simply call:
gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition()
gridView.getLastVisiblePosition()

I did something exactly as what you wanted to do. So I used that to only fetch the images that are needed.